# Bash Console commands (Codeship console): how to exit from current "inputs"

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Excuse me for the imprecisions in the question but I don't know how it is called what I'm trying.

In the [CodeShip documentation](https://blog.codeship.com/codeship-ssh-debug/) is stated that I can pass to the SSH CodeShip debug build some commands using their command line application.

So, I should do something like `cs setup-commands` and I'm prompted with this:

```
rof@railsonfire_unique_string_sfivbe8bwucb9:~$ cs setup-commands
Your setup commands:
phpenv local 5.6
phpenv local 5.6
```

In `Your setup commands:` I put my commands but then, how can I "execute" them?
The second `phpenv local 5.6` line is wrote by the command-line application. I think is something to signal the command were taken, but the behavior is ever the same: I remain "blocked" in the command `setup-commands`. After setting `setup-commands` I have to set also `test-commands` but all the things I write are taken by `Your setup commands:`.

How can I "submit and exit" the command `setup-commands` to then launch `test-commands` and set those other commands?

I think this is something related to Bash, but I don't know what it is...

And I don't know which is the correct terminology.

Can someone help me with this? So I will can also update my question to be more precise. Thank you.

Comment: To the one who downvoted: thankyou for the help ;)

Comment: Do you have a `setup-commands` file that you can show? Perhaps it has an incomplete line (like a `grep x ${file}` with file an empty variable) ?

Comment: @WalterA, no I cannot provide a the contents of this file as it isn't developed by me, but is a tool installed when I create the build image of CodeShip build environment. I don't think, anyway, there are errors, but that  is simply some sort of my fault in using the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your case, but usually the input is considered finished, when th input file (in your case stdin) is closed.

Try to press Ctrl+D, it should end your input (and so signal the program hat you stopped typing for this session)

Comment: This was exactly what I were looking for: thank you!